# Unable to deploy Spring boot application in IBM WAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I have devoloped Rest application usning the spring boot application and generated the WAR file  .When this WAR file deploying ing WebSpher getting error unable deploying this WAR file.
My spring boot Version is 2.5.0 and java 1.8.
My pom file is;

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">;

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

    <version>2.5.0</version>

    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    <!-- <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> -->

</parent>

<groupId>com.kgisl.claimsux.registration</groupId>

<artifactId>Registration</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Registration</name>

<description>Claims UX Registration Application</description>

<properties>

    <start-class>com.kgisl.claimsux.registration.RegistrationApplication</start-class>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>

        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>

        <version>19.3.0.0</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

        <scope>runtime</scope>

        <optional>true</optional>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>

                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>

            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>

        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>

        <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>

        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>

        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> -->

    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->

    <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId> -->

    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->

    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->

    <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> -->

    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->

    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->

    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->

    <!-- <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> -->

    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>log4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

        <version>1.2.17</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>

        <version>2.5</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>javax</groupId>

        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>

        <version>7.0</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>

        <version>1.7.12</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>

        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>

        <version>1.3.2</version>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>3.2</version>

                <configuration>

                    <source>1.7</source>

                    <target>1.7</target>

                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>2.4</version>

                <configuration>

                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>

                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>

                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <!-- <plugin> -->

        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->

        <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->

        <!-- </plugin> -->

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>2.6</version>

            <configuration>

                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                <packagingExcludes>pom.xml</packagingExcludes>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<repositories>

    <repository>

        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory</id>

        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>

        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local</url>;

    </repository>

    <repository>

        <id>spring-milestones</id>

        <name>Spring Milestones</name>

        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>;

    </repository>

    <repository>

        <id>spring-snapshots</id>

        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>

        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>;

        <snapshots>

            <enabled>true</enabled>

        </snapshots>

    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>

        <id>spring-milestones</id>

        <name>Spring Milestones</name>

        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>;

    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>

        <id>spring-snapshots</id>

        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>

        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>;

        <snapshots>

            <enabled>true</enabled>

        </snapshots>

    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
```

Error:- I m getting error like Error creating bean with name:-

Comment: Remove compiler and war plugin, replace with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Finally make sure you have extended the correct classes to make it a deployable war file (see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment).

Comment: Can you share the actual error you're seeing? Presumably there's an exception with a stack trace. "Error creating bean" just tells you there was a problem and doesn't specify what the problem was.